# How to write Get-ChildItem registry sub-key names and selected values to CSV in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am taking a hive value and getting a list of sub-keys, then getting values of sub-key properties all defined by command line parameters. I would like to output them to CSV like so:

sub-key name | val-1 | val-2 | ... | val-n

I am not sure how to make the following script do this and could use some assistance.

```
param ($hive, $regkey, $type, $val)

#Set default hive to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
if(!$hive){
    $hive="HKLM:"
}
#Require a registry key to process
if (!$regkey){
    Write-Output "Please enter a registry key!"
}
else 
{
    #Set up the registry key
    $regkey = $hive+":"+$regkey
    #Get the child items from the registry key
    $registry = Get-ChildItem -Path $regkey -Recurse
    #Process the values
    Foreach($a in $registry) {
        #List the registry key child item
        $valname = $a | Split-Path -Leaf
        echo "Name: " $valname
        #Process each $val parameter value
        foreach($value1 in $val){
            ($a | Get-ItemProperty).Psobject.Properties |
            Where-Object { 
                $_.Name -like $value1
            } |
            Select-Object Name, Value |
            Sort-Object
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you encountering any errors when this script is ran?

Comment: Use a PSCustomObject to hold the values to Export to Csv.

Comment: @MasonSchmidgall No errors - It runs fine as is.

Comment: @postanote Thank you - I will look into PSCustomObject.

Comment: No worries, if you run into errors, of course, ping back.